# How to compare Datetime variables with lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, .net

Having a date reference UserJoinDate and the list of dates List friendsJoined I would like to count how many friends joined a service before UserJoinDate and how many as the same time or later.

I wrote the following lines but it doesn't work:

```
List<DateTime> joinersDates = getJoinersDates();
FriendsJoinedBeforeCount = joinersDates .Where(x => x < UserJoinDate).Count();
FriendsJoinedAfterCount = joinersDates .Where(x => x >= UserJoinDate).Count();
```

Does anyone know how to count how many dates from the list joinersDates are before UserJoinDate and how many the same or after?

## Edit

Here is the Copy from ImmediateWindow:

```
churnersDates.Count( x => x > UserChurnDate)
Expression cannot contain lambda expressions
```

UserJoinDate Is DateTime

**Example:**

```
UserJoinDate = 9.11.2010 0:30:00
```

(the value is copied from Date: {9.11.2010 0:00:00}
    Day: 9
    DayOfWeek: Tuesday
    DayOfYear: 313...)

and

```
joinersDates.First() = 17.5.2011 0:30:00
```

Thanks!

Comment: DateTime compare should work fine the way you are doing it. Make sure getJoinersDates() returns correct List<DateTime> and UserJoinDate has value

Comment: Please define "does not work": what error message do you get? Compile time or runtime?

Comment: You can also do `joinersDates.Count(x => x < UserJoinDate);`

Comment: how is UserJoinDate defined? I mean you did not share its declaration.

Comment: Yuo don't need second expression. Here is the alternative `FriendsJoinedAfterCount = joinersDates.Count - FriendsJoinedBeforeCoun`

Comment: Your statements should work, there must be something wrong with getJoinersDates(); by the way this `joinersDates.Count(x => x < UserJoinDate);` is enough

Comment: How are the dates represented? e.g. Does UserJoinDate have a time component and the Dates in the list dont? Might be a mismatch based on time

Comment: `churnersDates` is what?

Comment: You can't use Lambdas in the immediate window, this is expected behavior. However your code should work fine when executed.

Comment: Hey can you expand on the **not working part** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
List<DateTime> joinersDates = getJoinersDates();
FriendsJoinedBeforeCount = joinersDates.Count(x => x.ToUniversalTime() < UserJoinDate.ToUniversalTime());
FriendsJoinedAfterCount = joinersDates.Count - FriendsJoinedBeforeCount ;
```

Or try to use Ticks property:

```
List<DateTime> joinersDates = getJoinersDates();
FriendsJoinedBeforeCount = joinersDates.Count(x => x.ToUniversalTime().Ticks < UserJoinDate.ToUniversalTime().Ticks);
FriendsJoinedAfterCount = joinersDates.Count - FriendsJoinedBeforeCount ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try comparing using Year, Month and Day property of DateTime separately like this;

```
FriendsJoinedBeforeCount = joinersDates .Where(x => (x.Year < UserJoinDate.Year) && (x.Month< UserJoinDate.Month) && (x.Day < UserJoinDate.Day)).Count();
```

Comment: Kindly also give reason when you say better. Helps everyone.

Comment: What about the dates where joinersDates year < UserJoinDate year but joinersDates month > UserJoinDate month?

Comment: I have given the logic of comparision roughly. but that is how comparision can be made.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be a limitation of Visual Studio, not a bug within your code. Visual Studio 2010 does not support the definition of lambda expressions within its Immediate or Watch windows.

If you really want to test a LINQ expression whilst debugging, you should encapsulate it into a method and call that from the Immediate window.

For example:

```
private int GetFriendsJoinedBeforeCount(DateTime joinDate)
{
    List<DateTime> joinersDates = getJoinersDates();
    return joinersDates.Count(x => x < UserJoinDate);
}
```

Then, in your Immediate window, you would call:

```
GetFriendsJoinedBeforeCount(UserChurnDate)
```